# Rerun of a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, function

im working on a existing website and the code is built with functions .
now , i have a function that fetches the ID of an article , and in this function theres a function that puts a value that says "username X has enter Article Y" 
now problem is , that it should go in to the database only once , but it seems to go in once with the title and it keeps going in the DB without a title for a few times . no idea why . it isnt my code .
any chance you guys have a solution how i can resolve this issue ?

i should add that i checked for loops and it doesnt seem to be in one .

```
function article($id = null){

    if(!$id) return 0;

    countViewsByPost($id);

    $qq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $id AND valid='1'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qq);
    $markup = null;

 history_actions( 'משתמש '.userID('username').' נכנס לכתבה '.$row['title'] );

    $markup .= '<br /><br /><br /><br /><div class="container p0 mb10"><a class="goBackContent" href="'.base_url().'articles" >חזור</a></div>';


    if(mysql_num_rows($qq) > 0){
        $markup .='
            <div class="container pb30 br8 content_page">
                <div class="container container-main-h2">

                    <h5 style="color:#000000;">פורסם ב '.date('d.m.y',strtotime($row['created'])).' ע"י '.get_level_of_user($row['userID']).'</h5>
                    <span style="color:#000000;"><b>צפיות</b> : '.$row['views'].'</span>
                    <div><div class="fb-share-button" data-href="'.base_url().'articles/'.$row['id'].'" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div></div><br>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center mb20"><h1>'.$row['title'].'</h1></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">'.$row['text'].'</div>
            </div>  
        ';



        $markup .='
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));</script>
        ';
    }
    else{
        header('location:'.base_url());
    }

    return $markup;
}
```

the code of the history

```
function history_actions($action = FALSE){

    if(!$action){
        return false;
    }

    $action = mres($action);
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $userID = mres( userID('id')) ;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO history_actions_web(userID,ip,action) VALUES($userID,'$ip','$action')";
    // var_dump($sql);die();
    mysql_query($sql);


}
```

Comment: Even, we won't have any idea, until you will show the code

Comment: Please attach code to your question so you get a better answer

Comment: i added the code

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: im using MYSQLI , this isnt my code bro lol . this is someone elses .

Comment: Then perhaps let the author of the code posting, he will probably be able to answer more accurately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history_actions function must be called only if an article exists.

```
...
if(mysql_num_rows($qq) > 0){
    history_actions( 'משתמש '.userID('username').' נכנס לכתבה '.$row['title'] );
...
```